# Class Decorators Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, python-decorators

I'm new with python and I don't clearly understand how class decorators are used.
I saw what using @decorator_name before a class or a fct does but I dont understand what is happend when you type multiple rows with decorators before a class.

Ex:

```py
@decorator(definition=)

@decorator(definition=)


class Employee(Person):

    @staticmethod
    rest_of_the_code
```

Comment: Are you asking about how to *use* a class as a decorator, or just about using a decorator *on* a class?

Comment: I found [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/) very interesting. It also covers class decorators and their uses.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.